# jQuery Datatables filter position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm working with jQuery datatables and I'm trying to position the filter/search box on the same row as the header of the div that's holding the datatable.

Here's a screenshot of the page:

[image]

And here is the markup:

```
    <div 
    style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(163,153,163,1); padding-top:5px; padding-left: 15px;  padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; ">

<h2>Funding Summary</h2>

<asp:ListView
    ID="lvFundingSummary"
    OnItemDataBound="lvFundingSummary_ItemDataBound" 
    runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblResearchArea" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlName")%>' />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFundingGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FundingGross", "{0:c}")%>' />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AllGross", "{0:c}")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table 
            ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" 
            style="width: 100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;">Research Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">Gross</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">All EPRI Gross</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Total(s)</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalFunding" runat="server" /></b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalEpriGross" runat="server" /></b></td>
                </tr>          
            </tfoot>

            <tbody runat="server">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>

        </table>                            
    </LayoutTemplate>          
</asp:ListView>

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var table = $('#itemPlaceholderContainer').dataTable(
               {
                   "scrollY": "300px",
                   "scrollX": true,
                   "scrollCollapse": true,
                   "paging": false,
                   "autowidth": true,

                   dom: 'frti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',
                   buttons: [
                       'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                   ]
               });

       });
 </script>
```

Funding Summary is the header, I want the filter box to line up to the right of it, flush against the right side of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create your own filters and add them to any element in your page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($('#filters-area'))
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4ruvq6dr/

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround here:

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html

I added this style:

```
.filterPad{
padding-top:15px;
}
```

and then added the following to the function:

```
dom: '<"toolbar"><"filterPad"f>rti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that a workaround, rather that (in my opinion) is how you should do it.  Another solution would be putting a style on input type="search", but you would need to be careful so it doesn't apply globally.